# Loopback custom route req object has empty body property even when request has a body

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, loopback, body-parser

I'm trying to figure out how to get cookie auth working in loopback. I have created a custom route in server/boot/router.js with this:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.post('/api/login', function(req, res) {
    app.models.User.login({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    }, 'user', function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        res.send('<a href="/">YA FAILED</a>');
        return;
      }
      res.cookie('access_token', token.id, { signed: true , maxAge: 300000 });
      res.render('token', {
        email: req.body.email,
        accessToken: token.id
      });
    });
  });
}
```

middleware.json:

```
"parse": {
  "body-parser#json": {},
  "body-parser#urlencoded": {"params": { "extended": true }}
},
```

When I make this call:

[image]

it gets into the route function, but req.body is just {}.

Why is this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the checked circle form-data to x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Worked, thanks. In my app I'm using "fetch" which just has a "body" param, which must not be using x-www-form-urlencoded. Will have to research that. Appreciated!